# Is my understanding of the proof of rearrangement theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, absolute-convergence

I'm reading the proof of *rearrangement theorem*. Could you please verify if my understanding of the last part of the proof is correct or not?

> [image]

---

1. The authors said

> The inequality $(8.3)$ implies the absolute convergence of $\sum x_{\sigma(k)}$.

I think the inequality $(8.3)$ implies that $\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}| \le \sum_{k=0}^{N}|x_{k}| + \varepsilon$ for all $m \ge M$. As such, the sequence $(\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}|)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded and thus it converges. Since $(\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}| )_{m \in \mathbb N}$ converges, $\sum x_{\sigma(k)} := (\sum_{k=0}^{m} x_{\sigma(k)})_{m \in \mathbb N}$ converges absolutely.

2. The authors said

> We see that $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon$, so the values of the two series agree.

I think because $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{N} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon$ holds, $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon$ holds for all $n \ge N$. As such, we take the limit  $n \to \infty$ and get $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}- \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{or equivalently} \quad \left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon$$

We again take the limit  $\varepsilon  \to 0$ and get $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k}\right| \le \lim_{\varepsilon  \to 0}\varepsilon = 0  \quad \text{or equivalently} \quad \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k}$$

As such, the values of the two series agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. Let $S:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x_{\sigma(k)}$. Then $\big| S-\sum_{k=0}^n x_k\big|\le\varepsilon$ will indeed follow for $n>N$, but your reasoning is not enough. 
   Use that, just as for $N$, there's also an $M'(\ge M)$ for $n$, such that all indices $0,1,\dots,n$ are present within $\sigma(0),\dots,\sigma(M')$.

   Once it's proved, we can simply finish by the definition of limit, as for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have an $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $|S-\sum_{k=0}^n x_k|\le\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hi  Berci. From your comment, I supplement the authors' proof with more details, and posted it as an answer below. Could you please have a check on it?

Answer (score 0):

From @Berci's answer, I fixed my attempt here.

---

**My attempt:**

For each $\varepsilon>0$ , there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{m}|x_{k}|<\varepsilon$ for all $m>N$. Taking the limit $m \rightarrow \infty$ yields the inequality $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}|x_{k}| \leq \varepsilon$.

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$. For each $n \ge N$, let $p_n =\max \{\sigma^{-1}(0), \ldots, \sigma^{-1}(n)\}$ we have $\{\sigma(0), \ldots, \sigma(p_{n})\} \supseteq\{0, \ldots, n\}$. Then we have $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{m} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_{k}\right| \leq  \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left|x_{k}\right|\leq  \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\left|x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon, \quad m \geq p_n, n \ge N \tag{8.2}$$ and also $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{m} |x_{\sigma(k)}|-\sum_{k=0}^{n}| x_{k}| \right| \le \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x_k| \right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x_k| \le \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |x_k| \leq \varepsilon, \quad m \geq p_n, n \ge N \tag{8.3}$$

In the particular case $n=N$, the inequality $(8.3)$ becomes $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{m} |x_{\sigma(k)}|-\sum_{k=0}^{N}| x_{k}| \right| \le \varepsilon$ for all $m \ge p_N$. This implies $\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}| \le \sum_{k=0}^{N}|x_{k}| + \varepsilon$ for all $m \ge p_N$. Consequently, the sequence $(\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}|)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded and thus converges. Since $(\sum_{k=0}^{m}|x_{\sigma(k)}| )_{m \in \mathbb N}$ converges, $\sum x_{\sigma(k)} := (\sum_{k=0}^{m} x_{\sigma(k)})_{m \in \mathbb N}$ converges absolutely.

We take the limit $m \to \infty$ in $(8.2)$ and get $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_{k}\right| \leq  \varepsilon, \quad n \ge N \tag{8.4}$$

We continue to take the limit $n \to \infty$ in $(8.4)$ and get $$ \quad \left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k}\right| \leq \varepsilon$$

Finally, we take the limit  $\varepsilon \to 0$ in the above inequality and get  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{\sigma(k)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k}$$

As such, the values of the two series agree.